# Converting a XML string into a JSON string is not giving desired outcome

Tags: json, json.net

I am using NewtonSoft.JSON for parsing a XML document and building a JSON string But I am not getting desired output. My xml  string is given below

```
<fulfillment>
       <tracking_number/>
        <line_items>
              <id>466157049</id>
              <quantity>1</quantity>
          </line_items>
   </fulfillment>
```

And after converting the XML to JSON it is giving the below JSON

```
{"fulfillment":{"tracking_number":"er2222222","line_items":{"id":"464194075","quantity":"1"}}}
```

But I need the JSON as below as my XML cam contains multiple line_items data.The difference between above and below JSON is the array bracket after line items element. when I am using two line_items in the xml it is giving the desired result but with single line_items it is not returning array like JSON format in the line_items section.

```
{"fulfillment":{"tracking_number":"er2222222","line_items":[{"id":"464194075","quantity":"1"}]}}
```

What is the way out to resolve the issue.

Thanks
Utpal Maity

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few changes in the xml. It should look like this:

```
<fulfillment xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'>
  <tracking_number>er2222222</tracking_number>
  <line_items json:Array='true'>
    <id>466157049</id>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
  </line_items>
</fulfillment>
```

Serializing this xml sample with JSON.NET will result in the json string you need. Adding multiple `line_items` nodes will give the expected result. Example with multiple `line_items`:

```
<fulfillment xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'>
  <tracking_number>er2222222</tracking_number>
  <line_items json:Array='true'>
    <id>466157049</id>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
  </line_items>
  <line_items>
    <id>466157050</id>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
  </line_items>
</fulfillment>
```

Calling the following code with above xml sample:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("Location of the xml file");
var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xml);
```

will result in the following json string:

```
{
    "fulfillment": {
        "tracking_number": "er2222222",
        "line_items": [
            {
                "id": "466157049",
                "quantity": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": "23",
                "quantity": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But is there any other way to do this without changing the structure of the document because this XML is coming from different source and I cannot modify the structure easily.

Comment: This is the way I'm aware of. But if you load the xml into a `XmlDocument` and you know its structure, you can always add the attributes you need and serialize the xml into json format that is suitable for you.